# URL Redirection from classic to lighting in salesforce

Tags: apex, url, salesforce-classic

I am trying to retrieve the HTML content of the Classic view page, but I keep getting redirected to the Lightning page.

```
String classicUrl = '/' + classicId + '?nooverride=1';
String htmlContent = (new pageReference(classicUrl)).getContent().toString();
```

It returns the HTML content only when I have Salesforce Classic opened in my browser window, which is not a suitable condition.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.

You can call salesforce switcher link to make a instance of the classic.

```
//creating classic instance to access classic record
pageReference switchToClassic = new pageReference('/ltng/switcher?destination=classic');
String htmlContent = (new pageReference('/' + classicId)).getContent().toString();
//creating classic instance to access Lighting record
pageReference switchToLightning = new pageReference('/ltng/switcher?destination=lex%27');
```

this won't change the view of the user also.